# how to split the string which containing underscore, dash and space

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string like

```
$str = "hyper text-markup_language";
$keywords = preg_split("/[_,-, ]+/", $str);
```

i used preg_split, but it split the string on the basis of underscore and dash not on the basis on space.

i want result like this

```
[0] = hyper
[1] = text
[2] = markup
[3] = language
```

Comment: `$keywords = preg_split("/[-_ ]+/", $str);` Keep hyphen at 1st or at last position.

Comment: Just remove the `,`

Comment: thanks, it's working for me.

Answer (score 9):

Nice and simple solution.

```
<?php
$str = "hyper text-markup_language";
$arr = preg_split("/[_,\- ]+/", $str);
var_dump($arr);
?>
```

This produces this output.

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'hyper' (length=5)
  1 => string 'text' (length=4)
  2 => string 'markup' (length=6)
  3 => string 'language' (length=8)
```

The issue was when you were writing the `-` character, the RegEx was reading this as a range value from the comma to the comma (which obviously is just a comma).

Escaping the hyphen and removing the duplicate comma (the square brackets mean list of anything inside) will produce an array.

#### RegEx explained

Square brackets are referred to as [Character Sets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).
They will match anything that is in them. See this example.

```
/gr[ae]y/
```

This will match `gray` and `grey`. This is because the square brackets are matching the `a` or the `e`. Changing the above to `/gr[a-e]y/` would mean that `gray`, `grby`, `grcy`, `grdy`, and `grey` would all match. This is because the hyphen (`-`) is a special character that will create a list from what is before the the hyphen to what is after it.

An alternative (following @anubhava comment) is to put the hyphen at the beginning or end of the character set in order for it to not need escaping since there it cannot create a range if there is nothing in front or behind it.

Comment: Thanks, this solution was super helpful! I was struggling trying to use `explode()` for something similar, this did the trick for me to just grab the first word in a file name, `explode()` wasn't playing well with underscores, this works perfectly! :)

Answer (score 2):

@user3056158 you can also do it without preg_split() like below :

```
<?php
  $str = "hyper text-markup_language";
  $str = str_replace(array(" ", "-", "_"), " ", $str);
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r(explode(" ", $str));
?>
```

Comment: why not, but you don't need to put the space in the array.

Comment: @ Casimir et Hippolyte you are right but i just used to show his all three characters

Answer (score 1):

Your `[_,-, ]+`  pattern matches one or more symbols that are either `,`, space or a comma, it does not match a hyphen. See [the demo here](https://regex101.com/r/8t6JTN/1).  The reason for it is that a `[,-,]` creates a range between a comma and a comma, thus matching only a comma.

You may use `[\s_-]+` as the regex pattern to match one or more (due to the `+` quantifier) symbols from the set (either whitespace (matched with `\s`), `_` or `-` (as at the end of the character class it is parsed as a literal `-` symbol)).

```
$str = "hyper text-markup_language";
$res = preg_split('~[\s_-]+~', $str, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($res);
// => Array ( [0] => hyper [1] => text [2] => markup 3] => language )
```

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/P0NIsx).

You may read on [character classes at regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Comment: BTW, you may read on [character classes at the SO `regex` documentation page](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/1757/character-classes).

Answer (score 1):

you should write it like this .

```
[-_ ]+
```